# Passing a class as argument to a function and use it's methods

Tags: python, function, class

Quite simple, I wanna pass a class to a function as argument, while the class that I'm using has several methods. Here's the class: (parent is also a `Node`)

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,parent,foods):
        self.state = state
        self.foods = foods
        self.parent = parent

    def getParent(self):
        return self.parent

    def getFoods(self):
        return self.foods
```

And somewhere else in a function I'm passing this class to function, but seems that I can't use all attributes. Here's the function:

```
def CalculateSomethingAboutThisNode(node):
     daddy = node.getParent()
     foodsOfDaddy = daddy.getFoods()
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
line 551, in CalculateSomethingAboutThisNode
   foodsOfDaddy = daddy.getFoods()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getFoods'
```

Please hep me out here.

Comment: import pdb; pdb.pm() is very useful for backtracking and figuring out what bad inputs you got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The node has no parent. In other words: it's a root node.

As such it can happen that `daddy` is `None` and that means `daddy.getFoods()` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

you should correct your code:

```
def CalculateSomethingAboutThisNode(node):
 if not node is None:
  daddy = node.getParent()
  foodsOfDaddy = daddy.getFoods()
```